# Gravity Forms filter for adding taxes at render and deleting taxes before submision

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to help my friend with his WordPress WooCommerce website where he is using Gravity Forms on all of his products. Say he's selling T-Shirts with logos on them. On the T-Shirt product page, the customer would input on a form "quantity", "number of colors", "express delivery", etc., where the total price gets affected by the customers inputs.

Since we're in Sweden, we'd like to have an option for the customer to select whether he's browsing the website as a company or personally. This is because companies does not necessarily want to see prices including taxes. Therefore, we'd like to simply remove 25 % from all prices on a form before it gets shown to the customer ([gform_pre_render](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_pre_render/)), and add 25 % on all prices on that form before it gets onto the customers cart.

The cart should show all prices excluding taxes. All prices on the website is excluding taxes.

Comment: Where will that option dropdown/radio will be? At the cart checkout screen, or inside the products? You have to make a dissension and settle where the option will be. In my opinion, best thing would be to list both prices (one with tax and one without it) when viewing a product and at the checkout the client selects whether they are a company or for personal use and then calculate the field values at the final cart checkout view by applying a filter to the `woocommerce_billing_fields`.

Comment: @christos_lytras the options are on the product page. I agree that your idea would be optimum; but I'm applying this on an already working website. I can't make too many changes to the existing system. I fear that adding two prices in one form would be more of a struggle. I will have a look at the filter you referred to.